# a for loop for a string that has vertices, edges and faces

Tags: python, string

```
complex = {1},{2},{3}, {1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3} this is my string.
```

I want to create a loop that gives me saying ok this has

```
vertices = 3
edges =3
faces =1
```

I can do it for "particular" structure using CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS. But I want it to give  me no matter how many vertices edges and faces I input so that it will count properly. 
My issue is the {} how can I deal with this. This has 2 loops right? Just can figure how to command.

the code I have is the only thing I can do. Please help. I am new to python.

```
def nsimplex(vertices, edges, faces):
    sum = vertices + edges + faces
    if sum == 14:
         print('This is a Tetrahedron')
    elif sum == 25:
        print('This is a 4 simplex')
    else:
        print('this is a nsimplex')

    sentence = 'the sum of {} and {} and {} is {}.'.format(vertices, edges, faces, sum)
    print(sentence)


def count():
    vertices = int(input("enter number of vertices: "))
    edges = int(input("enter number of edges: "))
    faces = int(input("enter number of faces: "))
    nsimplex(vertices, edges, faces)

count()
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Is English your native tongue?

Comment: The pieces of your post don't seem to make sense together. They seem vaguely related, but the string you say you have doesn't make sense with the rest of your post, and the code does something that doesn't match the English description of your task. It's highly unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What are you asking...You are taking your requisites as raw input from user itself ? \

Comment: @user2357112 Ok. I apologize for the confusion caused. So what I need is the following. Lets say I define a complex(A triangle) using {1}, {2},{3}(It has to be in curly brackets) etc etc notation. I want to write a program that will count {x} as one vertex and {x,y} as an edge and {x,y,z} is a face.

Comment: @TusharGupta Sorry for the confusion. I wrote what I need in the above comment. The code I wrote is something I wrote that will out put the number of vertices and edges and faces given that I make some conditional statements. This require the user to know about the complex(tetrahedron, triangle) before writing the code. I took that route and it didnt work. So I want a much more efficient way to program my intended task.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis Sorry for my run on sentences friend. I wrote what my question is in my second and 3rd comment. Yes English mite as well be my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```py
comp = {1},{2},{3}, {1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}

print "vertices =", map(len, comp).count(1)
print "edges =", map(len, comp).count(2)
print "faces =", map(len, comp).count(3)
```

(I'd avoid using `complex` as a variable name, since it is a keyword in Python.)

---

**Edit:** In case your input data is indeed a string, you can simply evaluate it:

```
comp = eval("{1},{2},{3}, {1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}")
```

---

**Edit:** If you really really really want to implement it the lengthy loopy way, here you go:

```
comp = "{1},{2},{3}, {1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}"

pos = 0
vertices = edges = faces = 0
while pos < len(comp):
    if comp[pos] == '{':
        pos = pos + 1
        count = 1
        while comp[pos] != '}':
            pos = pos + 1
            if comp[pos] == ',':
                count = count + 1
        if count == 1:
            vertices = vertices + 1
        elif count == 2:
            edges = edges + 1
        elif count == 3:
            faces = faces + 1
    pos = pos + 1

print "vertices =", vertices
print "edges =", edges
print "faces =", faces
```

(I hate code like that. But if you need to use two loops thats probably a reasonable solution.)

Comment: Thank you. This works can you give me a hint on how to do this using loops. Like a frame work. My task is to use minimum 2 loops. One loop goes for the main string. Second loop has to tell me that when the code sees { start counting and when it sees } stop counting. I have been trying to code it that way for the past 4 days and no progress. Sorry to trouble.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble again and thank you for your time.